# How can I remove maven dependency jar in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I'm really new to Maven and just converted my app-engine project to a Maven project.
I've added dependencies in the `pom.xml` file in order to get rid of the errors.
but now I get in my code

> The method getPart(String) is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

So after doing a bit of research on Stack Overflow it appears I need to have a single and updated package of `servlet-api` to make that work properly.

Apparently I may have a conflict with an older version that is in my Maven dependencies but I never added it in the `pom.xml` and now I'm stuck with this jar not knowing why it is imported and how I can delete it.

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my-project</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                 <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                 <deploy.promote>true</deploy.promote>
                <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mailjet</groupId>
        <artifactId>mailjet-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
</project>
```

and here are images of what I get in `Maven dependencies` in my build path.

my guess is that the error comes from having a 2.5 version of the servlet-api.

[image: build path section]
[image: eventual conflict with servlet-api 2.5 and 3.1]

So any help is greatly appreciated, I saw something about the `exclusion`
tag but don't even know where to put it as it doesn't look like anything in the `pom.xml` is asking for this jar.

Comment: You can use `mvn dependency:tree` to print the dependencies along with their transient dependencies. One of your dependencies most likely has a dependency on an older version of servlet-api which is why you get the conflict. You can add exclusions for that dependency as explained here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment.This is what I though but I'm using m2e and don't know how to use the command line plus my terminal window isn't working on my eclipse

Comment: @Babyburger also th link you provided me exclude a file not a dependency from downloading. is there any ways to figure out with eclipse the dependency that requires the olde version of servlet. Many thanks in advance

Comment: If your terminal window in Eclipse is not working, you need to reinstall Eclipse. You cannot properly use Maven without a console window in Eclipse.

Comment: Not that long before I've resinstalled it but it says `Could not create the view: org.eclipse.tm.terminal.view.ui.TerminalsView`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd better open in Eclipse your pom.xml file and switch to the "dependency hierarchy" tab. Look for the undesired library (type in "serlvet" in the filter) and add exclusion on it through the context menu. This will modify your pom.xml file.

Comment: Thanks I didn't tried the solution but I've managed to make it work by removing the google cloud platform library that remained using javax.servlet 2.5

Answer (score 1):

Delete project from workspace and don't check Delete project content on disk. Delete the jar from .m2 folder as well.  Import the project using eclipse. Open the pom file and click on dependency Hierarchy. Select the the jar you want to delete. Right click and click on Exclude Maven Artifact. Next time you run the proejct it will not download the jar.